# What is the difference between "and all" & "and everything"?

Tags: idiom-meaning

What is the difference between "and all" & "and everything"?

Is that just "all vs everything"?
I am reading *The Catcher in the Rye*. I think I got the nuance of that expression, but I would like to get an explicit explanation.

Comment: Please give the complete sentence. The answer depends on context.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, the two words can be used interchangeably. "Everything" is a pronoun, essentially, taking the place of a number of nouns:

> *Did you stop by the store and get the milk, bread, eggs, and sugar?*
>
> *Yes, I got the milk and everything.*

"All" is used similarly, though it is a determiner with its noun/s dropped from the sentence:

> *Did you stop by the store and get the milk, break, eggs, and sugar?*
>
> *Yes, I got the milk and all [of those things].*

Comment: I am assuming "and all" means "as well" in this book "The catcher in the RYE". I am talking about informal idiom. Then I found "as everything" in later page of the book. thats why I was just curious about usage of those terms.

Comment: In that case, "and all" can certainly mean "as well".
It can also be used to mean everything that goes along with the noun/s in question.

Comment: @Yoshiyuki Sekiguchi: I may be wrong, but I have the feeling ***and all** =  as well, also, too* is primarily a BrE colloquial usage. To work from Karmin's example here, it might occur as *Did you get the milk like I asked? Yeah - and I got a lottery ticket an' all*.